# When did the whole "hat" thing start?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2014

This is the first year I've done the whole "winter bash" thing, and I was interested; how did this tradition start? Mainly, who (and why, and how) invented the idea of *hats* on *avatars* (on SE and subdomains)?? It seems like a cool idea, but it seems like the weirdest thing ever. Any clarification is appreciated!

Comment: http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It originally started as [a promo on gaming.SE](https://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) as a reference to [the game Team Fortress 2](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) in 2011, called the Hat Dash.

Then [it was enabled on all sites that wanted it in 2012](https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash-2012), and was a huge success.

So in 2013 [it was brought back again](https://stackexchange.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013), and here we are with our fourth round of hats in 2014!

Comment: You linked to the 2013 promo for "this year."

Comment: @animuson Whoops, I'm bad at dates. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly where it started, but the first "hat fest" was on Arqade in December 2011: http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/